# Serialize an unsigned long long using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, nsnumber, nsjsonserialization

I have a REST API which expects a file size field to be in bytes. However I am observing that NSJSONSerialization is converting my value to an exponential representation which my server doesn't support.

For example:

```
unsigned long long fileSize = 100000000000;
NSDictionary *myObject = @{"fileSize": @(fileSize)};
NSData *dataToSend = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myObject options:0 error:nil];
// send dataToSend to network
```

On the wire I observe the following is sent:

```
{ "fileSize" : 1.0e+11 }
```

Is there any way to force NSJSONSerialization to retain the unsigned long long formatting on the wire?

E.g.

```
{ "fileSize" : 100000000000 }
```

Update: Corrected my sample code thanks to Gabriele Petronella

Comment: Also why are you using `NSData` in the first place? `NSJSONSerialization` works fine with dictionaries

Comment: The NSData is the payload I POST to my REST service.

Comment: There's no `NSJSONSerialization` in your question. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was able to solve this just now by explicitly initializing the NSNumber as an unsigned long long.

E.g.

```
unsigned long long fileSize = 100000000000;
NSDictionary *myObject = @{"fileSize": [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:fileSize]};
NSData *dataToSend = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myObject options:0 error:nil];
// send dataToSend to network
```

This resulted in the output I expected:

```
{ "fileSize" : 100000000000 }
```

Comment: weird, so it seems like the `NSNumber` boxing caused the issue.

Comment: yeah is an odd one. I can only assume internally it's using it as a hint for formatting?

Comment: the boxing syntax should expand to `numberWithUnsignedLongLong:` at compile time, so at runtime is should not matter. At this point I'm curious to see the IR clang produces in both cases.

Comment: The @ nomenclature is immature and may not work well in such edge cases.

Comment: So it would seem @HotLicks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `NSJSONSerialization` in your question, anyway converting the dictionary to a `NSData` instance seems wrong, and it's likely to be causing this encoding issue. Just do something like

```
NSDictionary *myObject = @{"fileSize": @(fileSize)};
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myObject options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: Ah sorry this was again a typo on my part.